# How do I create a ec2 launch template that automatically assigns an ipv6 address?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Trying to figure out what I need to put in the ipv6 setting to have one automatically assigned when creating an instance on ec2. I tried the following but get and error: "Invalid addresses: [2600:1f18:26e1:4c01::/64]" when I try to create an instance from the template.

[image: See]

Answer (score 1):

You specified a subnet. The field for IPv6 IP wants a single address. But if you really want the address automatically assigned, you should be leaving that blank anyway. Rather, your instance must start a DHCPv6 client to get its IPv6 address and related network information.

Comment: Can this be done using a launch template? I'd like a launch template that sets up the ipv6 address for me.

Comment: @StevieD Sure, you can put in the IPv6 address you want, if you want to manually assign it. But your question said you wanted them assigned automatically.

Comment: So, in other words, there is no way to use the launch template to automatically assign an ipv6 address to the instance.

Comment: You leave it blank! That's how you get an address assigned automatically.

Comment: When I leave it blank no ipv6 address is assigned.

Comment: @StevieD Is your instance properly configured? See the answer as written. And does your VPC actually have an IPv6 subnet?

Comment: I do have an ipv6 subnet and can assign ipv6 address to an instance and it will work (but I've been assigning them manually).

I ended up contacting amazon support. They confirmed there is no way to do it with a launch template. However, they referenced this link: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-ip-addressing.html#subnet-ipv6 This tells you how to get to the "Modify auto-asign IP settings" page where you can check off the "auto-assign IPv6" checkbox.

Comment: @StevieD Well, that's a bizarre default behavior.

Comment: Why is assigning an ipv6 address to an instance automatically bizarre?

Comment: @StevieD I said the default behavior of _not doing so_ is bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

There is now an ‘**IPv6 IPs**’ section under ‘Advanced network configuration’ in Network settings of the launch template, which allows you to specify how many IPv6 IPs to automatically assign regardless of wider settings.

[image]